# Switch statement uninitialized variable

Tags: java, switch-statement

The following code gives me : `The local variable str may not have been initialized`

```
public class experiment{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        int day = 1;
        String str;

        switch (day) {
        case 1 : str = "nice";
        break;
        }

        System.out.println(str);

    }


}
```

So, I gave `str` a `null` value, and it worked but I'm still wondering why the one on the docs work without initializing the value first, I've triple checked and I don't think I have any typos:

```
public class SwitchDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int month = 8;
        String monthString;
        switch (month) {
            case 1:  monthString = "January";
                     break;
            case 2:  monthString = "February";
                     break;
            case 3:  monthString = "March";
                     break;
            case 4:  monthString = "April";
                     break;
            case 5:  monthString = "May";
                     break;
            case 6:  monthString = "June";
                     break;
            case 7:  monthString = "July";
                     break;
            case 8:  monthString = "August";
                     break;
            case 9:  monthString = "September";
                     break;
            case 10: monthString = "October";
                     break;
            case 11: monthString = "November";
                     break;
            case 12: monthString = "December";
                     break;
            default: monthString = "Invalid month";
                     break;
        }
        System.out.println(monthString);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because there's a `default` case statement in the `switch` of the documentation example. It's called if no other `case` statement matches. In your own code, you have no such "fallback".

Hence, there's always at least one statement that's called, which will always initialise `monthString`.